# Unknown div with class " v-toolbar__content" in html when inspecting element from the browser

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I was trying to update the styling for one of the components (Header) with a code of something like this

```
<template>
 <v-app-bar>
  <v-avatar>
   <v-img />
  </v-avatar>
  <p></p>
  <v-spacer />
  <v-btn></v-btn>
  <v-btn></v-btn>
 </v-app-bar>
<v/template>
```

When I inspect the element in the browser. A div of class v-toolbar__content. Suddenly showed up. How can I access this v-toolbar__content so I can change its CSS?

The v-toolbar__content shows after <v-app-bar. It wraps the avatar up to the btn

EDIT: here's what it shows in when you inspect it in the browser

```
<v-app-bar>
 <div .v-toolbar__content>
   <v-avatar>
    <v-img />
   </v-avatar>
   <p></p>
   <v-spacer />
   <v-btn></v-btn>
   <v-btn></v-btn>
  </v-app-bar>
 </div>
</v-app-bar>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Vuetify is a collection of Vue.js components. Your source code which is relying on Vuetify is compiled to HTML before being sent to the browser. That's why you can't see the HTML in your source file. 
You can still style the div normally using css with .v-toolbar__content in a style block (If you are using SFC). You should take a look at both vuetify & vue.js doc. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: I actually have tried this, in case I can manipulate it even if it's hidden. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: did you wrap it in v-app and v-main?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that when you tried to manipulate the `.v-toolbar__content` class, you were using a scoped style ?

If that's the case, one way to manipulate your class is to use deep selectors to manipulate your child components (see the [doc](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements))

The following syntax should work.

```
<style scoped>
   >>> .v-toolbar__content {
      /* ... */
   }
</style>
```

(replace `>>>` with `::v-deep` if you're using Sass)

Comment: this worked for my vue issue with said element, thank you

Answer (score 0):

v-toolbar__content is part of v-app-bar.
If you use Vuetify you have surround your code once with v-app and then with v-main for vuetify to kick in. You can style your v-app-bar using Style or css Classes:

```
<v-app>
  <v-main>
     <v-app-bar style="color: red" class="red-toolbar">
       <v-avatar>
          <v-img />
       </v-avatar>
       <p></p>
       <v-spacer />
       <v-btn></v-btn>
       <v-btn></v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
  </v-main>
</v-app>

<style scoped>
   .red-toolbar{
      color: red;
   }
</style>
```